# How to install applications on blackberry z10 Simulator for testing

Tags: installation, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

How to install applications to blackberry z10 Simulator,usually in older versions of simulator we used browse from file section -->load java program and load the desired file on simulator, But for BlackBerry Z10 The Simulator can be entirely run on virtualmachines(like vmwareworkstation),

The only way i figured it out is

create an bb sandbox account-->download the desired application from it, any alternative to install bar files/bb z10 files straightaway into simulator of blackberry z10?

I need to install without using eclipse,any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use command line tools to do this without Eclipse. Some of them are listed [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/c_understanddevenv_use_commandline.html), and a complete deployment example is shown [here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/07/blackberry-10-command-line-development/).

You'll need a debug token for your simulator (`blackberry-debugtokenrequest`), package your app (I think you're already doing it as you're exporting to the sandbox) with `blackberry-nativepackager`, then deploy with `blackberry-deploy`.